# SCDF server gets "connection refused" when connecting to skipper

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Sorry for the unstructured question and the lack of protocol, this is my first post...  Please go easy on me :/

Installed SCDF on K3s cluster, helm chart: v26.5.4
SCDF version : 2.11.2

I am able to register applications in SCDF, but I get a connection refused when I click on the streams menu item.

I am using the default bitnami SCDF helm chart.

values.yaml

```yaml
server:
service:
type: LoadBalancer
loadBalancerIP: "192.168.66.156"

image:
debug: true

configuration:
trustK8sCerts: true

skipper:
enabled: true
image:
debug: true

configuration:
trustK8sCerts: true

flyway:
enabled: true

rabbitmq:
enabled: true

hostAliases:
 - ip: 10.43.0.1
 hostnames:
  - kubernetes.default

auth:
password: "1111"
seurePassword: false
erlangCookie: "xxxxxxxxxx"

mariadb:
enabled: true
jdbcParameter:
useMysqlMetadata: false
```

Connected to Skipper (on port 80) from a container without an issue.

[Error displayed on the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aM0Y.png)
[other error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbwqG.png)

Solution / Fix:

I downgraded to Helm 23.1.3 and SCDF version : 2.10.3

Working now on that version...  :(

Comment: The Bitnami team does the Helm chart. 
Which k8s distribution are you using? Have you tried any of the installation mechanisms in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/releases/download/v2.11.2/spring-cloud-dataflow-oss-install-2.11.2-rp1.zip?